# How to remove records from CSV in C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to remove records from CSV formatted text file. here is my code for reading and inserting records:

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = constr;
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand COM = new OleDbCommand();
    COM.Connection = con;
    COM.CommandText = "select * from shop.txt where id like '" + textBoxSearch.Text + "%'";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(COM);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);
    COM.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    con.Close();
```

But it dont work for remove. the remove query is like this: `delete * from shop.txt where id like <something>`

Note: when calling `ExecuteNoneQuery` following exception is occurred

OleDbException: Deleting data in a liked list is not supported in this ISAM.

Comment: The query would just be "delete from shop.txt..." No * in the delete statement.

Comment: Ahh. I missed the last part of your question too. Looks like updates and deletes are not possible using CSV files with OLE. You might have to think about using some other data format if you can. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281759

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows from a textfile is not easy - so the OLE adapter doesn't support it. Some options:

- Select the data you want to keep into a `DataTable` and then export it to a csv file.
- Parse the CSV file, filter unwanted lines and write all other lines into another CSV file. This might be a bit faster than using OLE to load all the data into memory and then dump them back out.